# Word for "influencing or manipulating people without their knowledge"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the word that describes the process of influencing people without their knowledge?

For example, "Social Media content is drastically influencing people's opinions without their knowledge".

Or should I leave the sentence as is?

Comment: What sentence are you talking about? (Your example sentence should be in your question.)

Comment: "Social Media content is drastically influencing peoples opinions without their knowledge"

Comment: OK, now [edit] your question to add your sentence.

Comment: The sentence in the title “influencing or manipulating people without their knowledge”  is the example I am referring to in the post body...

Comment: Snufkin, Laurel's point is that a question asked here should stand on its own, so people looking to answer it, or to learn from answers others have left, don't have to go looking through the comments to understand it. It will help if you edit your question so that it gives the context.

Comment: With 'manipulating opinions'  the word 'maniplulating' alone suggests their opinions were influenced without their knowledge .. (so influenced and without knowledge would be redundant with 'manipulating opinions' -- HOWEVER, 'manipulating' would suggest a deliberate way to push opinions, not an accidental or random direction of shift

Comment: So, my question is..  Is it like an advertising campaign that convinces someone they need something they don't really want?  Or is it like an adverstising campaign for a automobile that uses skinny models and inadvertently influences peoples self-image to feel inadequate about their shape even though the only message that ad wanted to make was to connect their car with tantalizing images unrelated to the car?

Comment: Yes, moreover, the word manipulation seems mostly negative. Wikipedia: "change the behavior or perception of others through abusive, deceptive, or underhanded tactics". I would much rather use "influencing people without their knowledge" rather than "manipulating people" if there is no substitute.

Comment: Closer to the latter, "advertising campaign for a automobile that uses skinny models and inadvertently influences peoples self-image to feel inadequate about their shape even though the only message that ad wanted to make was to connect their car with tantalizing images unrelated to the car"

Comment: Unrelated but not unimportant: _Peoples opinions_ needs an apostrophe: _people's opinions_

Comment: The word "covert" comes to mind.  But it implies intent.  Who's the actor in your sentence, or is there none?

Comment: Why is no one mentioning "Neuro-linguistic programming" ?

Comment: How about "deceiving"

Comment: What's wrong with manipulate itself? Is there a reason to avoid it?

Comment: @RodneyAtkins - Good catch.  Did you know that you can click on "Edit" below the question, and fix the punctuation yourself?  As an entry level participant, the edit will need to be reviewed by more experienced participants.  But that would definitely be an edit that would be approved.   You would improve the question, and earn 2 points by doing so!

Comment: I've tried, but edits have to be more than a certain number of  characters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term I would use is **subliminally**, the adverbial form of subliminal

> (of a stimulus or mental process) below the threshold of sensation or
>   consciousness; perceived by or affecting someone's mind without their
>   being aware of it.

The classic form of this is  [subliminal advertising](https://www.psychologistworld.com/influence-personality/subliminal-advertising)once thought to be widespread in movies. In this use, a single frame showing popcorn, inserted at intervals into the movie, was thought to induce a desire for popcorn without the viewer realizing that anything had happened. Other, more sinister,uses have been claimed, up to and including political campaigns.

So, your sentence might become, "Social Media content is drastically and subliminally influencing peoples opinions."

Comment: Just because you do not know something is being done to you, does not mean it is subliminal.

Comment: Subliminal is part of it - but do you think it makes sufficiently clear the cynical, unspoken intent of FB to harvest and market personal info?

Answer (score 13):

***Surreptitiously*** (ODO)

> - Obtained by ‘surreption’, suppression of the truth, or fraudulent misrepresentation;
> - Taken, obtained, used, done, etc. by stealth, secretly, or ‘on the sly’; secret and unauthorized; clandestine

So,

> "*Social Media content is drastically and **surreptitiously** influencing peoples opinions (without their knowledge)*".

Comment: OP is asking about deceit taking place in plain sight, not sneaking around in the shadows. It's a fantastic word, just not appropriate for this use.

Comment: @Will Crawford - Surely the whole point of the current upset with Facebook is precisely because it was not clear what they were doing.

Comment: @WillCrawford - Wouldn’t you describe all those ‘lifestyle’ quizzes deceitful. It certainly didn’t occur to me, initially, that their purpose was other than innocent and fun ?

Comment: Oh no, deceitful they are! It's just that *surreptitious* has a lovely long history of being used to mean rather literal cloak-and-dagger sneaking around (it comes from the Latin for, well, *creeping*). Please don’t spoil it ;o).

Answer (score 6):

"The word **gaslighting** is used to describe an attempt to destroy another's perception of reality."

And in the play which originated the expression, *Gas Light*, the gaslighter was a bigamist and jewel thief who manipulated his wife into not obstructing his attempts to recover a score.

It's typically used to describe abusive intentions, but (in my experience) has unfortunately loosened to include other attempts to shift the perceptions of others until they match what the manipulator wants them to believe. Either way, I am completely convinced that the social-media activity which you're asking about is indeed deliberately abusive and I find that "gaslighting" to be a very apropos description of what the perpetrators are doing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting

Comment: Gaslighting is a more specific term, describing a METHOD of achieving what was asked about.

Comment: +1, it certainly describes *a* process for subtly influencing someone ...

Comment: And it certainly fits the OP's one example given. If they were to give others, it might be clear whether a different term would be more suitable.

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively use the term **brainwashing**.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brainwash) defines ***brainwash*** as:

> *verb, transitive, US;*
>
> [T]o indoctrinate so intensively and thoroughly as to effect a radical transformation of beliefs and mental attitudes

Comment: I don't think brainwashing implies the manipulation happens without the individual's knowledge. In Asimov's Foundation the Mule's followers all knew they had been brainwashed.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the word ***indoctrination*** or ***indoctrinate***.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoctrination):

> Process of forcibly inculcating ideas, attitudes, cognitive strategies or a professional methodology by coercion.

The word applies to systemic manipulation, so wouldn't be appropriate if you're just  describing particulars on social media. However, given the way social media algorithms specifically curate content that reinforces the viewer's particular worldview (and even biases it according to some), it's entirely appropriate if you're criticizing social media generally.

---

> Social Media content is ***indoctrinating*** people without their knowledge".

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest **hoodwink**:

> Deceive or trick. ‘*staff were hoodwinked into thinking the cucumber
>   was a sawn-off shotgun*’

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hoodwink)

Comment: "Dupe" is another verb if Asker doesn't mind informal usage.

Answer (score 3):

The word "Warp" could be used, as in weather warping, or allowing to twist out of square, lumber that is left outside in wet weather.

"The lack of context, critical thinking or historical background in Social Media's presentation of issues is warping the peoples opinion's".

I believe exploitation of this condition is done subsequently but does not describe this activity.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, distort seems to fit better though.

Comment: I like this in that, while craftsmen particularly boatwrights , fine furniture makers, or musical instrument craftspeaople, will purposefully warp wood, that is no longer the popular primary notion of the word for an average person on the street.  More often than not, something warped is bent from inadvertent an unforseen neglect .. like leaving something on a window sill in the sun when they didn't think that was an unsafe place to leave it ...  or a contruction material that bent in the weather unfortunately.

Comment: Note, if a person uses "warp" (or 'distort', or another "skews" .. sending amiss)  another word would also be required - peoples ~priorities~ are warped/distorted ... saying it "warps people" or "distorts people" directly implies making them futher offbase or insane than I think the OP wants.  .. .but it might be "emotions" or "self-image" etc that gets warped or all three and more.

Comment: "_peoples opinion's_" has all the apostrophes in all the wrong places. May I suggest "_people's opinions_".

Answer (score 3):

I want to suggest ***sway***:

> Control or influence (a person or course of action)

Here are three examples from Oxford living dictionaries:

> - ‘This story absolutely outraged me and it is stories such as these that sway people over to thinking that capital punishment should be used on some criminals.’
> - ‘Did he influence Clara, or did she sway him in their initial decision to keep the concerto hidden?’
> - ‘How is it that you could easily sway Father when me and Brian have to literally beg for what we want?’

And there are more example on the internet

Comment: "sway" fits the bill well, but doesn't have as negative a connotation as what OP is looking for

Answer (score 2):

**Machiavellian** overlaps with both 'underhanded / deceitful / devious' and 'manipulative', as attested at this entry at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/machiavellian). 'Perfidious' and 'treacherous' also spell out the deceit involved. These are of course adjectives rather than  verbs.

[CollinsCoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/machiavellian) gives:

> If you describe someone as *Machiavellian*, you are critical of them
>   because they often make clever and secret plans to achieve their aims
>   and are not honest with people.

And [HarleyTherapy](https://www.harleytherapy.co.uk/counselling/machiavellianism-psychology.htm):

> *Machiavellianism* in psychology refers to a personality trait which sees a person so focused on their own interests they will manipulate,
>   deceive, and exploit others to achieve their goals.

In broadened usage, 'Machiavellian' relates to the behaviour as well as the character trait; thus there are examples of "Machiavellian attempt" and "Machiavellian methods" on the internet.

This broadened usage is licensed by [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Machiavellian):

> Machiavellian: suggesting the principles of conduct laid down by
>   Machiavelli; specifically: marked by cunning, duplicity, or bad faith
>
> *He relied on Machiavellian tactics to get elected.*

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian) also has relevant examples:

> *... while fending off the Machiavellian manoeuvres of others*
>
> *... repressive conventions of the times and the Machiavellian politics of those around her*
>
> *... a Machiavellian game of political ping-pong.*

Comment: Nah, that's the description of the influencer, not the manner in which they influence ...

Comment: @Will Crawford I suggest you look up "Machiavellian attempt" and "Machiavellian methods" in Google searches. And then 'broadened usage'.

Comment: You're actively trying to broaden the use, and in this case, make the word useless for its intended task. Machiavellian is still primarily about the manner and personality of the perpetrator.

Comment: @Will Crawford Are you suggesting that the thousands of examples of "Machiavellian attempt" and "Machiavellian methods" are all incorrect? Or that I myself have rapidly registered them? Usages change; sometimes they narrow, but often they broaden. ELU involves _usage_, not _One man's desired views_. // Essentially, you're saying that you're right here and [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/machiavellian) say is wrong: 'Machiavellian adjective _using clever but often dishonest methods that deceive people so that you can win power or control_'.  The _process_ involved.

Comment: A definition from an English Learners' dictionary, intended to help them understand the intent. Go look at Collins and Merriam-Webster. And it's still about the *behaviour*, as you quote, which is related to the actor not just the action.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Machiavellian):Machiavellian: suggesting the principles of conduct laid down by Machiavelli; specifically: marked by cunning, duplicity, or bad faith _He relied on Machiavellian tactics to get elected._ //  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian) has _ while fending off the Machiavellian manoeuvres of others_. / _repressive conventions of the times and the Machiavellian politics of those around her_ / _a Machiavellian game of political ping-pong_. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Machiavellian) ...

Comment: even has Machiavellian: _Attempting to achieve goals by cunning, scheming, and unscrupulous methods_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75577/discussion-between-will-crawford-and-edwin-ashworth).

Answer (score 2):

"Social Media content is drastically influencing peoples opinions without their knowledge".

I would use: "Social Media content is drastically influencing people's opinions **unbeknownst to them**".

> Robert Goodin observes that manipulation carries “especially strong
>   connotations of something sneaky” and that manipulation
>   characteristically happens unbeknownst to its victim.

There are tons of references out there that collocate with manipulation. I have only given two.

**The term specifically means without the knowledge of the person specified**.

[Merriam Webster - unbeknownst, aka, unbeknown](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbeknownst)

[unbeknownst](https://www.bgsu.edu/content/dam/BGSU/college-of-arts-and-sciences/philosophy/documents/conferences/2012/what-manipulation.pdf)

[unbeknownst](https://www.drgeorgesimon.com/lying-manipulation-tactic-1-pt-1/)

Answer (score 1):

> "Social Media content is drastically influencing peoples opinions
>   ***inconspicuously***".

ODO:

> **[inconspicuously](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inconspicuously)**
>
> *ADVERB*
>
> See **[inconspicuous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inconspicuous)**
>
> ‘He's less keen on persuading you with his big ideas than simply
>   putting them out there - and having done that he seems to slip out the
>   door quite ***inconspicuously***.’
>
> **[inconspicuous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inconspicuous)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   Not clearly visible or attracting attention.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion.

On a basic level, the *subliminal process* you're describing can be characterized as the *Machiavellian* **SUBVERSION** of traditional Western, Judeo-Christian values and free market society to *indoctrinate*, *bias*, *sway*, or otherwise *brainwash* people through *mesmerizing* media *propaganda*, historical *gaslighting*, and *surreptitious* *social engineering* to *inconspicuously* *warp* public opinion, *exploit* and *hoodwink* the masses, & further *instill* the consolidation of power and control into the hands of a small, elite ruling class. Other explanations are one or more of the following: *unbeknownst* ignorance, ego/bias, noise narratives, convenient dismissals of truth, or lesser derivatives of the aforementioned framework. This has been the revolutionary goal of the Fabian Society, for example, since its *inception* in the 1880s.

Now that we are aware of the ailment, how do we treat and destroy the disease?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the perfect fit, but the verb [**to exploit**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/exploit_1) seems like a word that's very close to the one you're looking for:

> make use of (a situation) in a way considered unfair or underhand.

Your example:

> Social Media content is **exploiting** people's opinions.

Comment: I think this is pretty good but is more subjective in the area of "without their knowledge"

Comment: Well, you sure can exploit people without their consent or knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**Mesmerising** is the word I would use.

*"Social Media content is mesmerising people without their knowledge".*

> **Franz Mesmer** (1734-1815)... who theorised that there was a natural energetic transference that occurred between all animated and inanimate objects that he called animal magnetism, sometimes later referred to as mesmerism.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Mesmer)

> The Internet Is **Mesmerised** By This Video Of A Snake Sipping Water

[NDTV](https://www.ndtv.com/offbeat/the-internet-is-mesmerised-by-this-video-of-a-snake-sipping-water-1831302)

> *3. trans. To affect (a person) as if by hypnosis; to fascinate, hold spellbound.*
>
> 1986   B. Fussell I hear Amer. Cooking ii. viii. 115   Froggers work in pairs, one to **mesmerize** the frogs..with a spotlight..the other to catch the frog by his legs.
>
> 1995   Independent 4 Mar. 25/2   There were his London superiors, **mesmerised** by the apparent profits he was making.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/116993?redirectedFrom=mesmerise#eid)

Answer (score 0):

Question: What is the word that describes **the process** of influencing people without their knowledge?

From Oxford Dictionary:

> [Propaganda](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/propaganda)
>   NOUN
>   1. *mass noun* : Information, especially of a biased or misleading nature, used to promote a political cause or point of view.
>
> Origin
>   Italian, from modern Latin **congregatio de propaganda fide** ‘congregation for propagation of the faith’ (see propaganda (sense 2)).
>
> propaganda (**sense 1** [cited above]) dates from the early 20th century.

From Wikipedia:

> [Propaganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda) is information that is not objective and is used primarily to influence an audience and further an agenda, often by presenting facts selectively to encourage a particular synthesis or perception, or using loaded language to produce an emotional rather than a rational response to the information that is presented.[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/propaganda) Propaganda is often associated with material prepared by governments, but activist groups, companies and the media can also produce propaganda.
>
> In the twentieth century, the term propaganda has been associated with a manipulative approach...

Noam Chomsky: [Propaganda and Control Of The Public Mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoNOQ7LMR8c) (full lecture on Youtube).

Answer (score 0):

To **instill**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instil):

> to put a feeling, idea, or principle gradually into someone's mind, so that it has a strong influence on the way that person thinks or behaves

Attribution:"Instil Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed April 05, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instil.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers already, but I just wanted to add **bias**. As in:

> Social media biases peoples opinions

Bias is more scientific and comes in many forms as [this infographic](http://www.visualcapitalist.com/every-single-cognitive-bias/) shows.

Answer (score 0):

Depends 'what' the writer is wanting to convey.  Consider the 'effect' on people is of greater import than Social Media. Perhaps re-arranging the sentence to emphasize this import would provide clarity.

Examples:

1. Peoples' opinions are being unknowingly and drastically influenced by Social Media.
2. People are unaware that their opinions are being drastically influenced by Social Media.

Answer (score 0):

**Social engineering** is a term for influencing or manipulating people without their knowledge. It can be used in a general sense, or in a context specific to information security. This question seems to be asking about general usage.

Social engineering is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(political_science)):

> efforts to influence particular attitudes and social behaviors on a
>   large scale, whether by governments, media or private groups in order
>   to produce desired characteristics in a target population.

Influence campaigns are a prominent application of social engineering. The objectives of such campaigns are not necessarily neutral or beneficial for all parties involved, although they can be. Examples include:

- the coordinated use of social media to affect outcomes in electoral politics
- improving health care outcomes or responsible savings for retirement by reinforcing recognition of long-term thinking over impulsiveness

The UK Behavioral Insights Team (under David Cameron) and US Social and Behavioral Sciences Team (under Barack Obama) were known as “nudge units”. They used behavioral science techniques for government policy. Via [Nudges: Social Engineering or Sensible Policy?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/partisan-pitfalls-and-moral-blind-spots/201702/nudges-social-engineering-or-sensible-policy) (*Psychology Today*), "The underlying philosophy behind nudges is libertarian paternalism: people should be free to make the decisions they want, but policymakers can present these choices in ways that lead to desired outcomes."

Social engineering generally has a negative connotation, of propaganda and deception, regardless of the ultimate goal. In [this article](https://www2.deloitte.com/insights/us/en/deloitte-review/issue-16/behavioral-economics-predictive-analytics.html) by public accounting firm Deloitte and Touche, regarding behavioral psychology, social engineering is likened to manipulation. It is not necessarily an unmitigated force for good:

> Many object to the idea of using psychology to nudge people’s behavior on the grounds that it is manipulative or a form of social engineering. These concerns are crucial and not to be swept under the carpet. At the same time, it is possible to view both behavioral data and behavioral nudge science as tools that can be used in either socially useful or socially useless ways. Hopefully the examples discussed here illustrate the former sort of applications. There is no unique bright line separating the usefully personalized from the creepily personal.

Answer (score -1):

Inception? Though I think it's not really in the dictionary (do correct me if I'm wrong), encapsulates what you have described. I think a more apt word may be "charm" or "subtle insinuation".

Comment: Do you mean _deception_? "Inception" is the name of a movie. The word _inception_ has a dictionary meaning, which is to begin something. It doesn't have anything to do with influence or manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yeah I was going on the basis of the movie. But deception is a pretty good word to use on this then.

Comment: Arkhaine, if the dictionary definition isn't matching up with the way you've heard a word used, then you need to include your own explanation and examples in your answer.

Comment: Basically using the word "inception" but how it was used in the movie and not in a dictionary whereby you plant the idea or influence the decision of a person. I've edited my answer to include a few more words that may be more appropriate