# Is there one word for "being deceived into complying"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word for "being deceived into complying"?

Example sentence to use it in would be:

> I will not be <deceived into complying> with the rules you have stated

Comment: 'duped' is a favorite of mine .. I'm not sure it is well enough used anymore to be understood

Comment: @Tom22 was gonna use it if you had not.  fav of mine too.

Comment: Also, "hoodwink"

Comment: wedge as in I will not be <wedged> with the rules you have stated

Comment: you have far more options with `by the rules` instead of `with the rules` , does that matter?

Comment: Also see [Word for “influencing or manipulating people without their knowledge”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/439957/239618)

Comment: "Conned" is a good word too.

Comment: @garageàtrois Add that so I can upvote it!

Comment: Is the "rule" part important?  I.e. does it matter that the person _complies with my rule_, or is it enough that they just _do what I want_?

Comment: What *goaded* you into choosing duped? Seeing as that even the answer says it has no connotation of compliance... It's just a synonym for tricked. Now I feel duped, but since I can use the DV arrow if I want, I'm 100% not in compliance. The definition of goaded might as well be, *I got you to do something that I wanted done* (with or w/o a stick).

Comment: @Mazura Well being duped means that you were deceived into an action. And that act was in compliance with what the duper wanted you to do. It might be argued that because you didn't truly understand, you weren't being compliant. But that defeats the whole idea. As a side note. It's not however the word I was looking for. I was actually looking for "placate". But my question was incorrect if "placate" was the desired answer. Because placation is not deception.

Comment: actually, @Mazura I said it doesn't 'strictly' imply compliance... but people choose 'tricked' if they only mean tricked, or conned or cheated in other one swoop losses... 'duped' is usually only chosen when someone gets brought into an ongoing situation with bad terms they are stuck with...  ... getting stuck with bad terms in a contract ... maybe 'duped into marrying them' , or 'duped into a timeshare contract'.  No it does not strictly mean compliance at all .. but an apt word for when forced into a situations that require ongoing compliance

Comment: For each of the suggested answers, like dupe and hornswaggle, the other person is the object/source of the deception, not "the rules".  The way the example sentence is constructed doesn't work correctly with these good answers.  `I will not be duped with/by the rules you have stated.` would be better phrased like, `You will not dupe me into submitting to the rules you have quoted.`

Comment: @geneSummons The intention was that the source of the deception is the individual or group behind the rules

Comment: @geneSummons you are correct on those points and even with 'into' there must be understood to be a suggested verb for the term 'duped' to be appropriately used  However I don't think it is a stretch that we idiomatically omit manh verbs that can be inferred.  'Forced me into terms/chains/positions/bankruptcy', 'Rushed me into statements/positions, "Lured me into danger/bed/situations"  Whether or not "rules" can be perceived as a status is a bit murky yet I think with "your rules" it gets more clear.  I will probably put a warning in my answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Duped is a good word used most frequently for being led into doing something by false promises or trickery

A very common way you would hear it saw would be in a retort "He's not going to dupe me into doing that!" or an excuse "Why are you invovled on that side of the mess anyway? " "He duped me into it" ..

(things like that)

> [**dupe** at dictionary .com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/duped)  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/duped
>
> 1. a person who is easily deceived or fooled; gull.
>
> 2.va person who unquestioningly or unwittingly serves a cause or another person:
>
> a dupe of the opponents.
>
> verb (used with object), duped, duping.
>
> 3.
> to make a dupe of; deceive; delude; trick.

While it might stretch the word a bit thin you might be understood without extra context

> I won't be duped ~into~ your rules.

(I know that is a bit different than your sample sentence)

It does not strictly mean 'complying' however it is very frequently used for being made a pawn to serve another's aims -

... but 'serving unquestioningly/unwittingly' and 'being compliant to' are pretty close. ... but 'being compliant to' and "complying to' are slightly different

Another trip-up: the idiomatic usage is "duped into VERBing something" or "duped into a situation". In a way, some of the "complying" is another idiomatic method were we will drop a necessary verb when a word suggests the verb that would apply.  Is "They were forced into unfair rules." ok or must it be "They were forced into complying with unfair rules." ?

I am just warning that there is something a little tricky in there. (thanks to @geneSummons comment in top section)

'Duped' fits the spirit of of a special type of deception that makes a person compliant.  "Tricked into rules" might also suggest compliance as 'xxxx into rules' assumes compliance ... but "Tricked" might merely 'mislead' into an action, not cast a spell to make someone compliant to anothers wishes.

Comment: Duped is the word that immediately popped into my head before I saw your answer, I think it fits the question perfectly.

Comment: Duped??????????

Answer (score 17):

You might find that the word **misled**, or **mislead** in present tense, works quite well.

From the prefix *mis-*

> Prefixed to verbs, with sense ‘badly’, ‘wrongly’, ‘perversely’, ‘mistakenly’, ‘amiss’.

And stem **lead** meaning, of course, to bring someone somewhere.

> I will not be **misled** by your arguments.

<sub>source: Oxford English Dictionary</sub>

Answer (score 14):

## Don't forget Hoodwinked, Bamboozled & Hornswoggled

From Merriam-Webster:

#### [Hoodwink](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoodwink)

> *transitive verb*
> 3 : to deceive by false appearance
> "I will not be hoodwinked <s>with</s> by the rules you have stated."

#### [Bamboozle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bamboozle)

> *transitive verb*
> 1 : to deceive by underhanded methods
> "I will not be bamboozled <s>with</s> by the rules you have stated."

#### [Hornswoggle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hornswoggle)

> *transitive verb*
> slang: bamboozle, hoax
> "I will not be hornswoggled <s>with</s> by the rules you have stated."

Comment: +1 for Hornswoggled. This is only the 2nd time in my life I encountered that word. And the previous one was almost 30 years ago. I really like it, but I am fairly certain very  few people who hear or read it will have any idea what it means.

Comment: @Tonny - Thanks!  A friend of mine used it often. Truthfully, I was half-surprised to find in in MW. ;-)

Comment: Man, these words are so fun. "Bamboozle" is especially awesome, I'd be so happily blown away if someone learning English threw that word out. Good answers!

Answer (score 10):

lull

2. To deceive into trustfulness: "that honeyed charm that he used so effectively to lull his victims" (S.J. Perelman).
   [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lull)
3. to calm (someone or someone's fears, suspicions, etc), esp by deception
   [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lull)

Or simply "trick"

> I will not be tricked into complying with the rules you have stated.

Comment: I have never seen lull used like that.....interesting. lull for lure?

Comment: @Lambie - Definitely [*lull*](https://www.google.com/search?q=lull&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b). E.g., 'lulled into a false sense of security'. Luring requires a reward. Lulling only requires you to *affect someone with complacency* (+1).

Comment: @Mazura Of course, lull is to make calm. I had just never seen with deceive as given here.

Comment: @Mazura: Definitely not *lull*. You don't lull someone with rules. *trick* is much better (but *dupe* really does it).

Comment: You can lull someone into playing by your rules.

Answer (score 8):

You may be looking for **manipulated**

Manipulation can be open (think of a 3-year-old knowingly flashing her winning smile to get her way) or covert, in which case it takes on the meaning you seek. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulate)'s 2b definition

> to control or play upon by artful, unfair, or insidious means especially to one's own advantage. Ex:
>
> > being used and manipulated by the knowing men around him —New Republic

Answer (score 8):

How about just plain **tricked**?

> Trick: a crafty or underhanded device, maneuver, stratagem, or the like, intended to deceive or cheat; artifice; ruse; wile.

Answer (score 5):

**inveigled**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inveigle) & [M-Wevster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveigle)

> to win over by coaxing, flattery, or artful talk to lead [someone into
>   a situation] or persuade [to do something] by cleverness or trickery

As in:

> I will not be *inveigled* with [by] the rules you have stated.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the term [**to cajole**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cajole):

> to persuade someone to do something they might not want to do, by pleasant talk and (sometimes false) promises

Your example sentence:

> I will not be **cajoled** into complying with the rules you have stated.

---

Another similar word would be [**to beguile**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beguile):

> trick (someone) into doing something

Your example sentence:

> I will not be **beguiled** into complying with the rules you have stated.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Mike R but those two don't replace the whole phrase

Comment: @MarthinusEngelbrecht Oh, I see. Honestly, I can't think of a single word like that. *To be ____ed into something* seems to be the pattern that one just can't escape when talking about deception and trickery.

Comment: "cajoling" can be pretty innocent and not always regretted.   Almost always it is with some sweet talk, flattery or friendliness and the false promises are usually more about 'puff' or other things for future benefit rather than the premise of the point at hand.  A child hugging and smiling and promising to brush their teeth extra well before bed might cajole their parents into a buying them a second scoop of ice-cream   (or more serious things, but usually with friendliness and sugarcoating the future than outright lies).

Answer (score 2):

The root word for gullible, though not often used these days is appropriate:

**[gulled](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gull)**  <-- see the verb entry

gull:  to deceive, trick, or cheat

Answer (score 2):

Though not so common, I always love a chance to use the word **Skulduggery**.

It can be used as a verb to fit your context:

> You will not **skuldug** my compliance with your fancy words!

From [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/181113?redirectedFrom=skuldugged#eid22434599):

> **skulduggery** n. Underhand dealing, roguish intrigue or machination, trickery.
>
> **skuldug**  v.  [as a back-formation.] nonce-wd. trans. to extract by trickery.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the answers provide synonyms for "deceived" but do not incorporate the "complying" element.

The closest I can come, though, to an answer to the question as asked is:

> I will not be a [sheep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sheep).

This, I feel, is quite close. It's not quite the part of speech you asked for but it does encapsulate in a single word not following a set of rules blindly or uncritically. The element of deception is strongly implied.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Conned** would be a good choice

> Persuade (someone) to do or believe something by lying to them.
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/con

Example:

> I will not be **Conned** with the rules you have stated!

Edit*

> As I re-read the question I would like to note that Conned fits your example better, however I would probably rewrite your example anyway if I were to pick any word currently answered, mine or other answers.
>
> > I will not be **Conned** into these rules!
>
> My original Answer included the word Pressured but due to Conflicting views on its application as well as my original opinion that conned was a better word I have moved it here for legacy purposes.
>
> I would personally use the word **Pressured**,
>
> > Attempt to persuade or coerce (someone) into doing something.
> >     https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pressure
>
> Example:
>
> > I will not be **Pressured** with the rules you have stated!

Comment: Coercion is far from deception.

Comment: @RonJohn The keyword is Persuade, you can use any method to persuade someone into doing something including deception. I would argue that Pressured still fits the question as asked.

Comment: You're wrong.  How do you *pressure* someone?  By applying *force* to them.  *Force* is in no way, shape or form *deception*.

Comment: @Daniel: Persuasion is convincing someone. Pressuring someone (coercion) is making them fear the consequences of not complying. Those who pressure others will try to describe their actions as persuasion, specifically to avoid the moral guilt that coercion entails. Someone who is pressured into doing something is **aware** that their choice is **forced** on them. Someone who is persuaded **voluntarily** chooses something **suggested**.Someone who is [what OP is looking for] **voluntarily** makes a choice thatthey believe to be a **free** choice but are **unaware** that it is **forced** on them.

Comment: @Daniel  Many times people are persuaded by logic to change their opinions as a rational response...  there is nothing wrong with trying to change the opinion of someone else. .. that is not trickery or deception. .. nor is it necessarily pressure.  Pressure would be more like a lighter form of blackmail .. also upfront, not deceptive ... "don't  expect me to go out of my way to do you favors in the future if you don't help me here" is pressure, but not coercsion or blackmail or deception..

Comment: Conned could work ... as it is most often deception used to get someone to take a subsequent act relying on false knowledge of circumstances (not merely finding ways to make people change their balance of cost benefit anaysis for themselves and not a single decision point but also a suggestion that they participate in subsequent actions that ultimately benefit person conning them )

Comment: @RonJohn I provided the oxford definition of the term pressured which states clearly "An attempt to persuade someone into doing something"the definition of Persuadeis to induce (someone) to do something through reasoning or argument

Comment: @Flater  I agree you are correct  in coercion is the evil brother of persuade, though I can still apply pressure through the use of persuasion. But I don't agree with your conclusion that OP is looking for free choice on the matter, there is no evidence on his examples background other then lying, which again is part of persuasion. Perhaps clarification is needed from OP.

Comment: @Tom22 Persuasion is the art of convincing someone to believe in something, there is no mention that it is limited to logical arguments. I can do nothing but flat out lie and so long as you agree with me I will have persuaded you. If my arguments put pressure on you due to the content then I will have applied pressure even if the argument was false.

Comment: @Daniel I won't disgree that it ~could~ be a lie that persuades someone, however, the OP asked for word that specifically meant 'deceive'  .. giving a broader word, and one use very often for kind and fine things like persuade, definitely would not firmly imply something underhanded.  "I didn't feel like going out to the movies but my friends persuaded me to get up join them.. I'm glad I did" . .. yeah you can use it the bad way.. although usually 'tricked' or 'decieved' or 'conned' or 'fooled' comes in if there was shady business

Comment: @Tom22 you are correct and that is the Main reason I have modified my answer, simple put Pressured while it could fit isn't specific enough for the OP.

Comment: **"_Conned_"** seems like a helpful suggestion, though it's difficult to +1 this answer because (_a_) **"_pressured_"** doesn't make any sense here and (_b_) much of this answer is weirdly formatted in a quote block.

Comment: Actually, after the accepted answer of **"_duped_"**, **"_conned_"** is probably the best answer to this question so far.  It's unfortunate that the rest of the post keeps folks from up-voting.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **Blinkered**

Horses pulling carts and wagons, or racing would often wear a set of Blinkers, a mask designed to reduce their field of view to just the road ahead so as to remove distractions and make them more compliant.

In the same way, your Opposition in the example is attempting to blind the subject to alternative courses of action.

See also: Tunnel vision

Or, as an alternative. **Railroaded**

Being forced down a single path by another agency, with or without your awareness of the fact. Particularly common in narrative games to avoid having to adapt to the player's choices.

Answer (score 0):

**Suckered**

The question addresses a ubiquitous issue of humanity.  We are always trying to persuade others by hook or by crook.  That is why there are so many valid answers.